# Try to delete selected item from listview and DB but my code will delete the previous item rather than the selected item

Tags: android, listview

Updated  code   for refreshing the listview  is not  working.

```
 @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    cd.open();


    cd.deleteRow(id+1);
    strings.remove(position);
    lv_arr = (String[]) strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try cd.deleteRow(position); in OnItemLongClick() method

Comment: are you storing the entries to table with same ids?? I guess not

Comment: cd.deleteRow(position); will  give  same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the id or position of selected item from listview, So you should know that the listview items are initialize with 0 position and it may be possible you have store items with id 1 and then increase it by 1.

So In this kind of situation either delete it by increase id by 1 or create one object for selected item and then pass it to remove.

**For first easy situation check below answer.**

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int      position, long id) 
  {

     Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + position);

      cd.open();
      //long i=id;
      //     i--;

      cd.deleteRow(id + 1);



      strings.remove(position)
      lv_arr = (String[]) strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



      // CView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
      //  Intent intent=new Intent(SqlView.this,SqlView.class);
      //   startActivity(intent);
      //   ret();

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have deleted a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Thks it will  work  but Can  you tell me how to refresh the listview ?

Comment: Yes sure, for that you need to declare arrayapdater global and then just assign value in it and on click when you delete item then notify it as data changed

Comment: I change to  this  but  still not    working                                                     private  ArrayAdapter adapter;
 cd.deleteRow(id+1);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You need to remove that item from lv_arr also then notify dataset changed check my edited answer and in it after lv_remove(position) line call notifychanged

Comment: as you have taken it as String array so you need to remove from arraylist strings and then again set lv_arr from strings and then notify dataset changed

Comment: On  this   private String[] lv_arr;        lv_arr.remove(position)  shows an  error on  remove

Comment: Not be able  to refresh listview even with this code.